# How to derive two abstract classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, interface

I have app structure -

```
public abstract class a 
{
}
//defined in a.dll
public abstract class b
{
}
//defined in b.dll

//Above 2 DLL reference added in main project where I want to derive both of this abstract classee like

public abstract class proj : a, b
{
}
```

I am able to derive any one of it only not both. So pls guide me on missing things or wrong coding I had done.

Comment: It is helpful if you quote the error you get. For example, if you get _error CS1721: Class 'proj' cannot have multiple base classes: 'a' and 'b'_, then bring that information in your question. It will make it more likely to be found when other people have a similar error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't multiple inherit using C#. You can however achieve this by using an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/87d83y5b(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

```
public interface Ia 
{

}

public interface Ib 
{

}

public abstract class MainProject : Ia, Ib  
{

}
```

C# interfaces only allow signatures of methods, properties, events and indexers. You will have to define the implementation of these in the `proj`  (MainProgram) class.

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class proj : a, b
```

This can't be done.  C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deriving from multiple abstract classes (which is illegal in C#), derive from two interfaces, (which are abstract by definition).

Answer (score 1):

You can't derive from two classes at the same time. You should use interfaces instead.

```
public interface IFirstInterface
{
}
public interface ISecondInterface
{
}

public abstract class Proj : IFirstInterface, ISecondInterface
{
}
```

Now classes that inherit from `Proj` will still need to implement all methods and properties defined in both interfaces.