# Generic type parameters at two levels of inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a base class for Test Instruments and their settings, which run various tests:

```
// these classes need to stay as-is
abstract class XmlSettings { }
abstract class TestInstrument<T> where T : XmlSettings { }
```

In a simple example, a TestInstrument is declared as follows

```
sealed class LivSettings : XmlSettings { }
sealed class Liv : TestInstrument<LivSettings> { }
```

However I have a case where there are some test instruments which have a lot in common, save for one property which derives from some other base class. This property is a type of laser. Here is an example

```
// base class of lasers
abstract class LaserBase { }
// two types of lasers
sealed class Engine : LaserBase { }
sealed class Blade : LaserBase { }
// base class for laser calibration test instrument. <XmlSettings> needs to be narrowed based on type of laser
abstract class LaserCalibrationBase<T> : TestInstrument<XmlSettings> where T : LaserBase { }
// settings class for each type of laser
sealed class EngineCalibrationSettings : XmlSettings { };
sealed class BladeCalibrationSettings : XmlSettings { };
// calibration class for each type of laser
sealed class EngineCalibration : LaserCalibrationBase<Engine> { }
sealed class BladeCalibration : LaserCalibrationBase<Blade> { }
```

Note this compiles however there is nowhere I am able to specify `EngineCalibrationSettings` or `BladeCalibrationSettings`, and then in place of them I use XmlSettings in `TestInstrument<XmlSettings>`. This is not right because I must narrow XmlSettings to the appropriate settings class.

*Need to address possible duplicate I guess. I can't use two Interfaces because each abstract class also has virtual methods with concrete implementation.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to derive two abstract classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432431/how-to-derive-two-abstract-classes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Kitson88 not exactly, because both base classes have concrete methods as well. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Apologies if I've misunderstood, but all I can see if that your attempting to inherit two abstract classes from a concrete class. If this is the case, then I would advise looking into consolidating `LaserCalibrationBase<T>` & `TestInstrument<T>` to interfaces which ultimately forces derived types to implement. You can inherit as many interfaces as you see fit.

Comment: @Kitson88 each abstract class has a lot of implementation inside. Otherwise they could be interfaces. If TestInstrument didn't have the generic type parameter, there would be no problem. That was my old design but I want to add the generic SettingsClass to add more automation. Used to be BladeCalibration : LaserCalibrationBase<Blade> and LaserCalibrationBase<T> : TestInstrument. That is how BladeCalibration inherited TestInstrument

Comment: There is a chain of inheritance. I'm not really looking for multiple inheritance. I intended to do this BladeCalibration : LaserCalibration : TestInstrument, however at multiple levels generic type parameters are required. I solved it by removing one of the generic type parameters so it's only needed at topmost level of inheritance.

Comment: I'm glad its resolved. Might be worth sticking it in an answer so others can visually see how you got around it.

Comment: @Kitson88 I simplified my question imo, and posted a workaround as an answer

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I am currently using is to only have one settings class for all types of laser

```
// base class of lasers
abstract class LaserBase { }
// two types of lasers
sealed class Engine : LaserBase { }
sealed class Blade : LaserBase { }
// base class for laser calibration test instrument. All laser types will use LaserCalibrationSettings
abstract class LaserCalibrationBase<T> : TestInstrument<LaserCalibrationSettings> where T : LaserBase { }
// settings class for all lasers
sealed class LaserCalibrationSettings : XmlSettings { };
// calibration class for each type of laser
sealed class EngineCalibration : LaserCalibrationBase<Engine> { }
sealed class BladeCalibration : LaserCalibrationBase<Blade> { }
```

This works because the settings classes are deserialized from xml. I can choose to include only the settings which correspond to each laser type in each respective settings object, and the other properties won't be used by the calibration classes (but are available, which is not desirable)

```xml
<LaserCalibrationSettings>
  <BladeName>Blade 1</BladeName>
  <!-- other settings -->
</LaserCalibrationSettings>
<LaserCalibrationSettings>
  <EngineName>Engine 1</EngineName>
  <!-- other settings -->
</LaserCalibrationSettings>
```

and (in vb.net)

```vb
Public Class LaserCalibrationSettings
    Inherits XmlSettings
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property BladeName As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property EngineName As String
    <XmlElement> 
    Public Property OtherSettings As Whatever
End Class
```

vs. what is more desirable

```xml
<EngineCalibrationSettings>
  <EngineName>Engine 1</EngineName>
  <!-- other settings -->
</EngineCalibrationSettings>
<BladeCalibrationSettings>
  <BladeName>Blade 1</BladeName>
  <!-- other settings -->
</BladeCalibrationSettings>
```

and

```vb
Public Class BladeCalibrationSettings
    Inherits XmlSettings
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property BladeName As String
    <XmlElement> 
    Public Property OtherSettings As Whatever
End Class

Public Class EngineCalibrationSettings
    Inherits XmlSettings
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property EngineName As String
    <XmlElement> 
    Public Property OtherSettings As Whatever
End Class
```

What is not desirable is that for instance in EngineCalibration, I can access the BladeName which is not applicible i.e.

```
sealed class EngineCalibration : LaserCalibrationBase<Engine>
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Settings.BladeName); // N/A!
    }
}
```

which is why it is only a workaround.